# É possível rastrear os arquivos .js que são chamados ao executar algum evento do JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, navegador-de-internet

Por exemplo, se um evento `click` aplicado em um *link* chamar uma função que está no arquivo `A.js`, que por sua vez precisa do `B.js`, que precisa do `C.js`. Gostaria de saber se tem como saber essa dependência entre os arquivos pelo *browser*.

Comment: Só pra ficar claro seu cenário, como estão estruturados seus arquivos? Pode adicionar um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) do seu código na sua pergunta?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode entrar no firebug e colocar um break point no corpo da função. Com isso você pode ir executando linha-a-linha e verificar em profundidade as outras funções que são chamadas.

Comment: E se usar Chrome ou IE, eles também incluem debuggers com a mesma funcionalidade. Só não sei sobre o Opera.

Comment: Posso apimentar a pergunta um pouco? Não que me interesse esse assunto, mas enfim... E para implementar algo similar mas num nível mais baixo para que não se dependa do browser?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Não dá, você não conseguiria interceptar o interpretador da linguagem para tratar os breakpoints.

Comment: Legal, mas já enriqueceu o teor do tópico mesmo assim ;)

Answer (score 1):

Exceto depurando linha a linha, não há como prever as dependências de uma determinada função ou trecho de código porque elas são resolvidas dinamicamente.

Se não houver um `eval` envolvido, seria possível, por exemplo, analisar o código estaticamente e determinar quais funções são chamadas. Então dá para procurar em todo o código e ver onde elas estão.

Entretanto, veja que este método é muito falho. Existem inúmeras situações onde isso simplesmente não funciona.

Veja, JavaScript não é uma linguagem fortemente tipada, então poderíamos fazer isso:

```js
var obj1 = {
    f: function() { return 1 }
};
var obj2 = {
    f: function() { return 2 }
};

function generica(obj) {
  return obj.f();
}

console.log( generica(obj1) );
console.log( generica(obj2) );
console.log( generica({ f: function() {return '?'} }) );
```

No exemplo, criei dois objetos `obj1` e `obj2`, cada um com a função `f()`. Depois declarei uma função `generica()` que recebe um objeto qualquer e executa a função `f()`.

Na terceira chamada a `generica()`, crio um objeto anônimo com uma outra função `f()`.

A saída no console será:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> ?

Note que não tem como saber a qual função `f()`ela se refere, até porque pode não ser nenhuma das duas primeiras. Somente podemos saber no momento em que `generica()` está executando.

Além disso, em JavaScript é possível também carregar e criar código dinamicamente, então existe código que simplesmente não está em arquivo algum.

Em tese, o navegador poderia varrer todo o código carregado em memória num determinando contexto, com a página carregada, de forma a identificar as possibilidades. Porém, a utilidade disso seria duvidosa.

Creio que esse tipo de dificuldade faz com que não haja muitas soluções (se houver alguma) para esse problema de rastreamento.

Bem-vindo ao mundo das linguagens dinâmicas. ;)